# List of derived objects

Tags: c#, .net

I need to keep a list of created objects in my application. I have an abstract object and a number of derived classes. I would like to keep a list of created objects in an attempt to not needlessly create new objects.. im trying to do this with the below code, where T is derived from AbstractMapper. but getting the error

> Cannot convert type 'AbstractMapper' to 'T'

when adding it to the list

```
protected List<AbstractMapper> Mappers = new List<AbstractMapper>()

public AbstractMapper Mapper<T>()
    {
        foreach (var mapper in Mappers)
        {
            if (mapper.Type == typeof (T).Name)
            {
                return mapper;
            }
        }
        var newMapper = GetClass<T>("mapper");
        Mappers.Add((AbstractMapper)newMapper);
        return (AbstractMapper)newMapper;
    }
```

Comment: whre do you get the error?

Comment: hi. thanks. on "Mappers.Add("

Answer (score 2):

You seem to lack the generic constraint to help the compiler make sure your code is type safe

```
public AbstractMapper Mapper<T>()
    where T : AbstractMapper
```

This way you constraint the usage to only these `T`s that inherit from `AbstractMapper`.

Anyway, the compiler should warn you that your `T` is not convertible to `AbstractMapper`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not seeing the following error?

> Cannot convert type 'T' to 'AbstractMapper'

The problem is that the compiler cannot guarantee that your generic type parameter `T` is a subtype of `AbstractMapper`.  You should add a generic type constraint:

`public AbstractMapper Mapper<T>() where T : AbstractMapper`

Then you could consider returning `T` instead of `AbstractMapper`.

You might also consider using a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`, where the key is `typeof(T)`.  If you want an object pool of derived types, you can also use a static field of a generic type:

```
public static class MapperProvider<T> where T : AbstractMapper
{
    public static T Instance = GetType<T>(); //static initialization
}
```

Each generic type created from the generic type definition `MapperProvider<T>` will have a different static `Instance` field, and looking up the appropriate instance from `Mapper<T>` is then as simple as returning `MapperProvider<T>.Instance`.